# Return first row in each group from Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Hi I need to come up with a query that efficiently returns just one record per group(I might be thinking about it wrong) and stop searching for more records in that group as soon as it has found one record.

This is my table:

```
|col1 | col2|
|-----|-----|
| A   |  1  |
| A   |  2  |
| B   |  3  |
| B   |  4  |
```

I want to return.

```
|col1 | col2|
|-----|-----|
| A   |  1  |
| B   |  3  |
```

Note that I don't actually care if in row one I have `A`,`1` or `A`,`2`(same applies to second row).
What I want is to get one record that has `A` in first column could be any record that matches that criteria, and similarly I want one record that has `B` in col1.

The closes that I know to getting this are two queries

```
SELECT col1, MIN(col2)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY col1
```

and the other:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE col1 = 'A' 
    AND ROWNUM = 1
```

First query is not good enough because it will try to find all records that have `A` in `col1`(in the actual table I'm looking at this means searching though millions of rows, and my indicies won't be of much help here). Second query will return just one value of `col1` at a time, so I'd have to run it thousands of times to get all the records I need.

NOTE:

I did see similar question in here but the answers were focused on just getting the right query results, I my case issue is how long do I need to wait for these results.

Comment: The first query is exactly what you need. Why do you think your indexes won't be of use? If you have an index on (col1, col2), there's every chance that Oracle will use the index. Otherwise it'll do a full table scan.

Comment: Indicies use col1 and col2 with another column that has dates in it and we are adding millions of records on daily basis. Basically I have two indicies one being (col3,col1) and the other (col3,col1). Finding one record without knowing what time is showed up(where on col3) takes  few minutes, I need to find thousands of such records. Basically given that it takes long time to find one such record I don't want Oracle to waste time looking for another record because I don't care if col2 returns max min or something in the middle.

Comment: You have two indexes, both on the same columns? I feel sure there is a typo in your comment there. Did you try your first query? If not, why not? Give it a go and see what happens. If so, what was the execution plan? It's possible you could benefit from an additional index, or something else like partitioning.

Comment: @Boneist I'm sorry you're right that's a typo. I'm running the query right now still waiting for results. As for execution plan DB is using INDEX SKIP SCAN to find the records. Lastly I'd love to add new index or a table but I'm not the dba here so I lack the credentials :)

Comment: I hope there's a process whereby you can request an index be added! I'm assuming here that this is something that is to be run periodically in the production database, rather than an ad-hoc query run infrequently.

Comment: I'm afraid that after running the query for 2,228.3 sec I had to kill it, record must be buried too deep in the table.

Comment: It's hard to advise you further without more details. We'd need to know more details, such as the actual query (you can anonymise the columns, table names etc), the corresponding explain plan, DDLof the table, including constraints and indexes (again, you can anonymise the names and exclude irrelevant details). In the meantime, I'd definitely try getting the index on (col1, col2) added!

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like this is the query you are looking for:

```
select col1
     , min(col2) keep (dense_rank first order by rownum) col2
from tablename
group by col1;
```

Comment: this increased the cost of a more complex query I have here.

Answer (score 0):

I feel the below query is returning the result quick.

```
 SELECT col1,col2 FROM (
        SELECT col1,col2, ROW_NUMBER () over (partition by col1 order by col2 asc) 
        minseq FROM tablename 
              --where rownum < 1000000000
        )
        where minseq = 1;
```

Normal query

```
SELECT col1, MIN(col2)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY col1
```

took 1 min to fetch 500 records out of 100000000 records and this query took 0.03 seconds

Comment: this triplicated the cost of my query in Oracle 12c